# dplyr: Mutate call throwing deep "Evaluation Error"

Tags: r, neural-network, dplyr

I'm working on a dataset of pokemon ([download](https://www.kaggle.com/terminus7/pokemon-challenge/downloads/pokemon.csv))([web-link](https://www.kaggle.com/terminus7/pokemon-challenge/data)). I'm attempting to turn a column of categorical variables into an int vector representation in preparation for creating a neural network. My [code is here](https://github.com/MatthewWolff/Scraps/blob/master/Pokemon/standardize.r). I made a function to do the 1-of-(C-1) effects-coding:

```
numerify_categorical <- function(categorical) {
      uniq <- unique(categorical)
      sorter <- lapply(uniq, function(x) {
        rtn <- integer(length(uniq)); 
        rtn[x] <- 1; 
        if(as.numeric(x) == length(rtn))
          rep(-1, length(rtn))
        else
          rtn
      })
      names(sorter) <- uniq
      return(sorter[categorical])
}
```

And it seemingly worked when I tested it by itself – it would return a list of vectors with correct values. However, as I attempt to use it within my mutate call, I suddenly get the following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
      Evaluation error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

I called traceback() on this error and found more details. Specifically, the error is originating from the following dplyr mutate call, where I use my custom function.

```
    mutate(Type1 = numerify_categorical(Type1), # take care of categorical variables
           Type2 = numerify_categorical(Type2))
```

The important part of the traceback reads as follows:

```
16: stop(list(message = "Evaluation error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.", 
    call = mutate_impl(.data, dots), cppstack = NULL))
15: .Call(`_dplyr_mutate_impl`, df, dots)
14: mutate_impl(.data, dots)
13: mutate.tbl_df(tbl_df(.data), ...)
12: mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...)
11: as.data.frame(mutate(tbl_df(.data), ...))
10: mutate.data.frame(., Type1 = numerify_categorical(Type1), Type2 = numerify_categorical(Type2))
```

I don't know what's causing this error, and I'd appreciate any feedback, since from searches that I've conducted I haven't had much luck. Some sources seemed to call on using "mutate_" or "mutate_each_", but I didn't have luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: I've realized that numerify_categorical function wasn't behaving with  Type2 because it was introducing NA's. To amend this, I just added a special case to the "sorter" function – if(is.na(x)) return(NULL).
Thanks